# Why do these two methods give me two different times?

Tags: ruby, codeblocks, proc

Both methods calculate the time it takes ruby to call and run a code block. I don't see any reason why these two methods should return different results.

methodone gives me: 1.000135157

methodtwo gives me: 1.000108267

I'm a noob, am I even doing this right? please let me know.

```
def methodone(a)
  start = Time.now 
  a.call
  result = Time.now - start
end

def methodtwo(a)
  start_time = Time.now
  a.call
  end_time = Time.now
  result = end_time - start_time
end 

a = Proc.new do {}
end

p methodone(a)
p methodtwo(a)
```

Comment: First is end-start, second start-end which explains negativeness. Difference in time may be explained by having run the code before. It's usually pointless to benchmark one call to small code since values will differ wildly. Run it a million times and call the function first before doing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't expect them to be exactly the same. There will always be something going on outside of the Ruby process that will impact performance. You should consider a margin of error of, say, 0.1%

```
def time(&block)
  t = Time.now.to_f
  yield 
  t2 = Time.now.to_f 
  puts t2 - t 
end

50.times do 
  time do 
    Proc.new { }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't get the same output always because the CPU of your machine can be less or more used by other processes running on your computer as well as some caching and interpreter optimizations can occur. For such simple methods you can't reliably time them by just a single pass. If you want to benchmark something like that it is better to tun it thousands or millions of times and then take an average. This will produce a more consistent result, because the "noise" of outside factors gets canceled out.

Comment: yeah there was a typo in my code. I fixed the end_time and start_time positions and i still get two different times